# Create a simple OpenCV pipeline with GStreamer

Tags: python, opencv, jpeg, gstreamer

I have a pipeline to stream images over UDP

```py
fps = 20
width = 500
height = 500

out_send = cv2.VideoWriter(
        "appsrc ! videoconvert ! "
        "video/x-raw,format=I420 ! "
        "jpegenc ! rtpjpegpay !"
        "udpsink host=127.0.0.1 port=5000",
        cv2.CAP_GSTREAMER, 0, fps, (width, height), True
    )

while True:
    frame = np.random.randint(255, size=(height, width, 3), dtype=np.uint8)

    out_send.write(frame)

    time.sleep(0.05)
```

This starts the pipeline but I am unable to receive using the following pipeline. The streaming wont begin, just hangs.

```sh
gst-launch-1.0 udpsrc port=5000 ! application/x-rtp,media=video,payload=26,clock-rate=90000,encoding-name=JPEG ! rtpjpegdepay ! jpegdec ! videoconvert ! queue ! xvimagesink
```

However if the frame is captured from webcam as below

```py
cap_send = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

fps = int(cap_send.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))
width = int(cap_send.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH))
height = int(cap_send.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT))

while True:
    ret, frame = cap_send.read()

    if not ret:
        break

    out_send.write(frame)
```

Then the receiving pipeline starts and streams without any issues.

In both cases I see the following message on the receiving end

```sh
Setting pipeline to PAUSED ...
Pipeline is live and does not need PREROLL ...
Pipeline is PREROLLED ...
Setting pipeline to PLAYING ...
New clock: GstSystemClock
```

Edit:

I ran the receiving pipeline with `GST_DEBUG=3` and see the following output

```sh
gst_rtp_jpeg_depay_process:<rtpjpegdepay0> discarding data packets received when we have no header
```

This only happens if the sending pipeline uses raw images / numpy arrays as above.

What am I doing incorrect here. Very new to gstreamer and need some help

Goal: To stream images generated in opencv, asynchronously.

Comment: Are you able to imshow frame in the first case? Is the shape and type of frame identical in both cases?

Comment: What happens if you remove the sleep in the first case?

Comment: imshow is able to create an identical frame in both cases.

no effect if i remove sleep

Comment: And .shape shows the exact same result? Can you try to use the same input resolution as in your webcam case? Im not sure whether jpeg needs multiple of 8,16 or 32 wudth/height.

Comment: Gstreamer source code has "if (frag_offset > 0 && gst_adapter_available (rtpjpegdepay->adapter) == 0)
    goto no_header_packet;" maybe some can interpret that. I dont have enough gstreamer or jpeg detail knowledge. With this comment: /* saw a packet with fragment offset > 0 and we don't already have data queued
+   * up (most importantly, we don't have a header for this data) -- drop it
+   * XXX: maybe we can check if the jpeg is progressive and salvage the data?
+   * XXX: not implemented yet because jpegenc can't create progressive jpegs */

Comment: One important thing i just noticed. The stream does not work for specific frame sizes. 
a frame size (630x100) (610x100) doesn't work. (620x100) (640x100) works

Comment: I was wrong in saying imshow was creating same frame sizes. 

The width and height are truncated if they are not divisible by 8. If the height is truncated the pipe works with some undefined values at the end. if the width is truncated then i just get a green frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Micka pointed me in the right direction.

The issue was with frame sizes. I have tried MJPEG and H264 and both need frame sizes (width/height) that are multiples of 8. Gstreamer will round them up to the closest 8th multiple. If the height is rounded then there is jitter seen at the end of the frame. If the width is rounded then a green screen is seen at the receiver.